# mixing beer with spirits, increase alcohol content?

Tags: alcohol

I decided to mix beer with vodka hoping it would make me more drunk due to the alcohol content but then remembered the rest ISNT alcoholic and i cant figure out if mixing beer with vodka or other spirits would increase the alcohol content or not i would really like an answer to this as well as any health risks if there are any, thanks.

Comment: Please note that whilst health risk discussion for individual cases are outside of the scope of this site, risks associated with alcohol are well known and available from good sources online: http://www.nhs.uk/livewell/alcohol/Pages/Alcoholhome.aspx

Comment: Perhaps it's worth adding for absolute clarity that the proposed mixing will definitely increase the total alcohol consumed e.g. comparing one shot of vodka with the same shot plus a beer - obviously. The linked answer discusses the physiological effect of this mixed drink.